# Make a landscape Layout in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My application has a navigation drawer that is composed by a main fragment container that change with other fragments when i want to change page. If switch to landscape when i'm in another page the application return to the home page(fragment container).And it's the same if i switch from landscape to portrait. How can i solve this problem? I think i have to change something in the main-activity but i really don't know how to do.

My java actually is like this.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        NavigationView navigationView = null;
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_breed) {
                // Handle the camera action
                BreedFragment fragment = new BreedFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this github code https://github.com/samerzmd/Navigation-Drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sam/navdrawerlockedplease/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem. You just need to add `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and then you can rotate the pohone without returnig to the home fragment.

Answer (score 2):

What you've done by defining `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` is essentially telling Android: "Hey, thanks for your awesomeness but DO NOT perform the default operation(s) when the phone is rotated or keyboard availability changes. I'm fully responsible and can handle this myself".

So it **seems** you've solved the problem but just to give you more clarity moving forward, the problem (as you already know) is with rotation. So I imagine the following lines above exist in the `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`?

```
NavigationView navigationView = null;
MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Before your specified `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `onCreate` of your `MainActivity` would get called **everytime** the device orientation changes.

So how do **really** solve the problem? The Android documentation best explains that, and all what I've just laid out [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).

Yes, it requires more work but it's worthwhile understanding and empowering yourself with making the right decisions accordingly.